# How to dynamic change image in gtk3

Tags: c, sqlite, gtk3, glade

i create gui that  display face who's not wear mask ,i create table sqlte3 in opencv(python)
and send filename to C by sqlite3
now i'm trying to Change my image dynamically in Gtk3 and im using Glade, i have filename in sqlite3 , i need to get filename from sqlite3 and show and change image continuously
but when i run it , it only display the last filename  .

```
///////// gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -rdynamic -o test2 test2.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -lsqlite3 -std=c99
```

here's is function for my program

```
G_MODULE_EXPORT void add_image_cb(GtkButton *button)
{
    sqlite3 * db;
    char * sql;
    sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
    int nrecs;
    char * errmsg;
    int i;
    int row = 0;
    char jpeg[] = ".jpg";
    char name[30];

    sqlite3_open ("list.db", & db);
    sql = "SELECT name FROM name_list";

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, strlen(sql)  , &stmt, NULL);

    while(1)
    {
        int s;

        s = sqlite3_step (stmt);
        if (s == SQLITE_ROW) {
            int bytes;
            const unsigned char * text;
            bytes = sqlite3_column_bytes (stmt, 0);
            text  = sqlite3_column_text (stmt, 0);
            
            strcpy(name,text);
            strcat(name,jpeg);
            printf ("Data of row %d is : %s\n",row,  name);
          
            if (next_image)
            {
                gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER(fixed1),pre_image);
            }
            //gtk_widget_hide(pre_image);
            next_image =gtk_image_new_from_file(name);
            gtk_widget_show(next_image);
            gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(fixed1),next_image);
        
            row++;
            //sleep(1);
        }
        else if (s == SQLITE_DONE) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            fprintf (stderr, "Failed.\n");
            exit (1);
        }   
    }  
}
```

thank you for reply :)

Comment: Hi, checkout the GTK `g_timeout_add` function. You may need to use `g_timeout_add (1000, fn_to_display_filename, NULL);` instead of the `sleep(1)`. (I had a similar problem recently where only the last image was displayed.)

Comment: It would help if you put-up something reproducible.